# How to dump/burn program into LPC2148

Tags: arm, embedded

I have LPC2148 daughter board but I am not able to dump/burn code into it, and it doesn't have any usb connector to dump code.
I read on internet by using FT232RL I can able dump code into LPC2148 but I am not able to do so. 
please give me solution 
thank you..!

Comment: If you don't have JTAG, LPC214x - like most NXP parts - has a ROM bootloader which allows programming over the UART, as Chapter 21 of the manual explains in great detail. You _have_ read the manual, haven't you?

Comment: The precise details of the board (a link to the manufacturer's spec or data sheet for example) would help you get an accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

The chip supports *In-System Programming* (ISP) via an on-chip boot loader ROM.

From the [User Manual UM10139](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10139.pdf):

> Programming of the Flash memory may be accomplished in several ways:
>   over the serial built-in JTAG interface, using In System Programming
>   (ISP) and UART0, or by means of In Application Programming (IAP)
>   capabilities.

The function of the FT232RL you mentioned is to act as a USB/UART bridge and is necessary primarily because modern PCs lack legacy RS-232 serial ports. You can in fact purchase a USB-Serial cable or adapter which will contain a bridge chip such as the FT232RL.  Most of these use RS-232 line level signals, so you would still need an RS-232 line driver/receiver to connect then to your board (if your board has a serial port, it probably already has a line transceiver and you can connect directly to that). It is possible from specialist suppliers including [FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm#TTL-232R-5V) themselves to get a USB cable with integrated FT232 and bare TTL level connections to connect directly to LPC2148 UART0 Rx/Tx lines.

If your board does not already expose a UART0 serial port and the necessart control to start the boot loader, a [Serial Port Bootloader Interface](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/714) board is available.  For that you may then also need a USB/Serial adapter or a PC with a legacy serial ports.

Once you have a suitable serial connection, you will need the LPC2000 Flash Utility software to run on the PC.

The JTAG option is however faster, and more powerful since the JTAG is both a programming and debugging port.  With a suitable toolchain and JTAG adapter it is possible to program and execute code with source-level PC hosted debugging including break pointing, data watching and single stepping of the code.

Comment: this "I'll read the manual for you"-service **must** be awarded ;)

Comment: Of course, you can also bit-bang JTAG with an FT232R too, so its function is not entirely unambiguous ;)

Comment: @Notlikethat : I'd never noticed that capability of FT232R, but it seems that if that were the suggestion an FT232H/FT2232H would be more suitable as it supports JTAG directly.